# Generating android apks from android project with multiple source set with gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have an Android application that has multiple sources that I can build from.

For example

```
 src/x/java
 src/y/java
 src/z/java
```

In the `build.gradle` file I have a productFlavours tag that include these sources. I know how to to this from eclipse,  manually, ( switching between different sources) but what I am interested in is the following:

How can I generate an apk for each and every one of these project, from the terminal, but still have all these apks to have the same app package name (I'm working with robotium right now , so I need that the apks to have the same package name as the apk that I get from building manually from eclipse).

Trust me , i read a lot before asking here , but i couldn't manage to succed , maybe i did something wrong , or maybe i was totally off , i don't know , but wherever i look , noone gives something like

Step 1 ... step n etc , and they don't stick to the point.

Comment: Hi ! I used to work a lot on this kind of problem, could you please provide a coding example ? Maybe a small project stored on github illustrating your problem ? Basically you'd like to switch from one source to the other using the terminal while always keeping the same package name. Are these android libraries ?

Comment: It's exactly how you say. In eclipse i have 2 source directories : "main" and the other one is connected to the folder on which i'm building the app , for example : src/main and src/x they are seen as source directories by eclipse. If i right click on project -> properties -> java build patch -> source , i can delete the "src/x" and put "src/y".

I can't put an example of the code because it's not mine  , i'm sry , i hope you understand what i tried to say.

Comment: Can you provide the gradle file which comes with the project ? I'm pretty sure you do something with flavours or build types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use flavors or build type :

```
productFlavors {
    flavor2 {}
    flavor1 {}
}

sourceSets{
    flavor1.java.srcDirs = ['src-flavor1'] 
    flavor1.res.srcDirs = ['res-flavor1']
    ...

    flavor2.java.srcDirs = ['src-flavor2'] 
    flavor2.res.srcDirs = ['res-flavor2']
    ...
}
```

Here's a good [link](http://blog.robustastudio.com/mobile-development/android/building-multiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/) about to do it properly. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I managed to make it work after all . I used flavours as in the link you provided and it worked. Thank you.

For everyone that was in the same situation as me , don't forget to add things in sourceSets as well, not just flavours.